# Plot python is showing empty value

Tags: python, plot, runge-kutta

I'm trying to plot a runge kutta equation, but it shows an empty value. Where did I go wrong in the logic?

```
for n in xrange(0,10):    
   k1 = R*T[n] + g*h[n]
   l1 = -1*r*h[n] - a*b*T[n]


   k2 = R*(T[n]+k1*not_dt/2) + g*(h[n]+l1*not_dt/2)
   l2 = -1*r*(h[n]+l1*not_dt/2) - a*b*(T[n]+k1*not_dt/2)


   k3 = R*(T[n]+k2*not_dt/2) + g*(h[n]+l2*not_dt/2)
   l3 = -1*r*(h[n]+l2*not_dt/2) - a*b*(T[n]+k2*not_dt/2)


   k4 = R*(T[n]+k3*not_dt) + g*(h[n]+l3*not_dt)        
   l4 = -1*r*(h[n]+l3*not_dt) - a*b*(T[n]+k3*not_dt)        


   T[n+1] = T[n] + not_dt/6 *(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
   h[n+1] = h[n] + not_dt/6 *(l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)


plt.plot(T[n+i],h[n+i])
```

Perhaps I try to simplify a bit

```
T[0] = 11
h[0] = 0

for test in xrange(0, 10):
    k1 = T[test] + h[test]
    k2 = 2*k1
    k3 = 2*k2

    T[test+1] = T[test]+k3
    h[test+1] = h[test]+k2
    print T[test+1], h[test+1]

plt.plot(T[test+1],h[test+1])
```

I've tried running simplified script above and it gives value for print, but it just wont showed up in plot. So the question is perhaps in the end not related to runge kutta after all, just some logic in plotting. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's impossible to read this. Can you indent your lines with 4 spaces to get monospaced code-like text? If it doesn't look like Python when you're done, keep editing it till it does.

Comment: I've edited it. I hope it's more readable.

Comment: Could you provide all the data needed to plot, please? So a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice since people not knowing _what_ you're calculating could know _what's_ going wrong with your code.

Comment: The initialization of your simplified code `T[test] = 11` and `h[test] = 0` is not runnable since `test` is undefined at this stage.

Comment: I've made a simplified script below that, with all the data needed. But it's not readable again, since I'm still ttrying to figure out how to make my script in good order

Comment: @FL: You should make sure that your code is runnable. After that, we _might_ solve any problems/errors. There are some implementations given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/792927/Fourth-Order-Runge-Kutta-Method-in-Python) and [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Runge-Kutta_method#Python).

Comment: Already it looks like the first thing to do is to start using NumPy. Then you won't need to do all this indexing and your code will get much more readable. And I assume you know about division in Python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the running index of the loop outside of the loop where it is not defined.

You attempt to plot exactly one point, not the arrays. Use

```
plt.plot(T,h)
```

provided both lists have the same length.

Comment: Yes! It works! So that's the explanation. Thank you. And thanks for people responding my question.